# How to filter for column that does not contain specific text - Impala / Hue

Tags: text, filtering, impala, hue

I'm new to using Impala via Hue and want to return results of a query that do not contain specific text in a column.

Data comes back like

```
"abc, def, hgi, jkl"
"abc, jkl"
"abc, def, jkl"
```

and I want to filter out results that include "abc" and "jkl".

I'm having a moment and think the answer here is very straightforward so please have mercy :).

```
SELECT * FROM `sch_edm`.`fact_blah_hub_booking`
where created_datetime >= '2019-01-01 00:00:00' 
and rate_access_code_shopped like '%def%' or '%abc%' is false

SELECT * FROM `sch_edm`.`fact_blah_hub_booking`
where created_datetime >= '2019-01-01 00:00:00' 
and rate_access_code_shopped like '%abc%' or '%jkl%' isfalse
```

Looking for results that exclude specific keyword values..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below query when run on Hue-Impala would exclude the records those have the column `rate_access_code_shopped` that contains the values `def` or `abc`.

```
SELECT * FROM sch_edm.fact_blah_hub_booking
WHERE created_datetime >= '2019-01-01 00:00:00' 
AND rate_access_code_shopped NOT LIKE '%def%' 
AND rate_access_code_shopped NOT LIKE '%abc%';
```

So, any records with values for the column `rate_access_code_shopped` containing `def` or `abc` or both `def` and `abc` would be excluded and returned as the result.

Let me know if it helps!